# Where can game assets for Blender be downloaded?

Tags: objects

Is there any place where I can download surroundings of a game as a 3d model, or maybe there are some inspired artists where they put them out for download? I'm trying to find rooms from Wall-e. Some rooms, or outside surrounding,s or some interior surroundings. Where can I find things like that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is does not pertain to blender.

Comment: @David we wanted to have some resource questions for textures and stuff, this should be community wiki. (I can't currently find one for game assets).

Comment: to David - I ment created in blender. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You might try [blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can find lots of downloadable assets at

- [BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com)
- [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends)
- [TF3DM](http://tf3dm.com/)
- [Yobi3D](https://www.yobi3d.com/)